# Citation undefined Cambridge template thesis

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using Cambridge template to write my thesis. I added a section for list of publication and tried to have the reference section in each chapter rather than for the whole thesis. 
I used the command

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{sectionbib}{natbib}
```

and always get 'undefined citation'.

I already uploaded the project on the Overleaf website and it works perfect there, but on my own computer I got the citation problem. 
This is the link for my project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/jzgpmgsgbhtj

when I run the bibtex I got this error message

I got this when i run bibtex

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) 
The top-level auxiliary file: build\thesis.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Dedication/dedication.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Declaration/declaration.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Acknowledgement/acknowledgement.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Abstract/abstract.aux 
I couldn't open auxiliary file ownpubs.aux ---line 33 of file build\thesis.aux : \@input{ownpubs.aux : } 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
I couldn't open auxiliary file Chapter1/chapter1.aux ---line 38 of file build\thesis.aux : \@input{Chapter1/chapter1.aux : } 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
I couldn't open auxiliary file Chapter2/chapter2.aux ---line 41 of file build\thesis.aux : \@input{Chapter2/chapter2.aux : } 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
I couldn't open auxiliary file Chapter3/chapter3.aux ---line 44 of file build\thesis.aux : \@input{Chapter3/chapter3.aux : } 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Appendix1/appendix1.aux 
A level-1 auxiliary file: Appendix2/appendix2.aux 
I found no \citation commands---while reading file build\thesis.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file build\thesis.aux 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file build\thesis.aux 
(There were 7 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Probably you need to be running `bibtex` locally (overleaf will do this for you automatically) in addition to `(pdf)latex`, take a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162).

Comment: It would be much better to use `biblatex` to have a bibliography per chapter.  The template supports `biblatex` by default, you just have to trigger the use.

Comment: Since the project works on Overleaf it is very likely that on your machine you forgot to run BibTeX. See Dai Bowen's link. Since your project does not use `biblatex` but `natbib` I have retagged your question.

Comment: Off-topic: Your version of the template is badly outdated. Some bugs have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Do you mean I need to download the template again? if yes, is it in the same website ?

Comment: Please, Is there any way to send you the project or its link?

Comment: All updates have been made upstream, i don't know if Krishna pushed them to the online compilers. It is always better to use a template directly instead of using templates from online compilers. They (online compilers) rely on updates by the template author, and they often forget to push updates.